# i am trying to use two while loop in a single program to iterate two queries but first while loop is not executed

Tags: java, jdbc

```
    public class JustTest  
    {  
        public static void main(String[] args)   
        {            
            //Blank workbook  
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();   
            String url ="";
            String username ="";
            String password ="";
               try  
               {  
                   Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  
                   Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);          
                   c.setAutoCommit(false);  
                   System.out.println("Opened database successfully");  

            //Create a blank sheet  
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("total");  
            Row headerRow = sheet.createRow(0);
            Cell date = headerRow.createCell(0);
            date.setCellValue("date");
            Cell byDate = headerRow.createCell(1);
            byDate.setCellValue("total au");
            Cell byDate1 = headerRow.createCell(1);
            byDate1.setCellValue("total au_dt");
            Statement stmt =  c.createStatement(); 
//passing two queries rs and rs1 
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select empname,empno from emp");
            ResultSet rs1=stmt.executeQuery("select deptno,deptname from dept");
            int row = 1;
//first query iterate
            while(rs.next()) {

                String empname= rs.getString("empname");

                int empno = rs.getInt("empno ");
                Row dataRow = sheet.createRow(row);

                Cell dataNameCell = dataRow.createCell(0);
                dataNameCell.setCellValue(dateValue);

                Cell dataAddressCell = dataRow.createCell(1);
                dataAddressCell.setCellValue(empno );
                row = row + 1;
            }
//second query iterate            
            while(rs1.next()) {
                String deptno=rs1.getString("deptno");
                String deptname =rs1.getString("deptname ");
                Row dataRow = sheet.createRow(row1);

                Cell dataNameCell1 = dataRow.createCell(2);
                dataNameCell1.setCellValue(deptno);

                Cell dataNameCell2 = dataRow.createCell(3);
                dataNameCell2.setCellValue(deptname );


                row1 = row1 + 1;
            }

               }  
         catch ( NullPointerException e )   
                    {  
                     System.out.println( " is not updated because cells cannot be left null/empty ");       
                    }  

          catch ( Exception e )   
                       {  
                         System.err.println( e.getClass().getName()+": "+ e.getMessage() );  
                         System.exit(0);         
                       }  

            try  
            {  
                //Write the workbook in file system  
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\jit\\Desktop\\allSheets\\justtest.xlsx"));  
                workbook.write(out);  
                out.close();  
                System.out.println("sheet.xlsx written successfully on disk.");  
            }   
            catch (Exception e)   
            {  
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }  
        }  
    } 

    java jdbc jdbc-odbc
```

there are two queries and i am trying to iterate the queries using two while loop ,but for me i am always fetching the data of 2nd loop from db..where as  first loop is not executed so data's are not stored for first loop..(storing data in an excel sheet) ..can anyone please edit the code so that data can be stored for both the loops..

Comment: Degug your code yourself, maybe?

Comment: U are  rewriting stuff.

Comment: i have just debugged it ..but always the first loop is getting skip

Comment: did you check if there is any data in the 'emp' table?

Comment: @nafas just for better information

Comment: Probably your first result set is empty

Comment: something must be going wrong with your query execute your query directly on database and see if you get any results

Comment: @batscream..there is data..and if i tried to execute only one while ie rs then data is stored to excel

Comment: @user3778684 then you should already know if your query gives any results back, if yes, edit your question to narrow down possibilities, if no - you know what to do.

Comment: @ɢʜʘʂʈʀɛɔʘɴ yes i am getting result for the same

Comment: @user3778684 please try as suggested in below answer, it seems logical sometimes but i am not sure because second query might be replacing your first result set

Comment: @user3778684 this part "try moving the rs1 query to below the first while loop."

Answer (score 2):

Move your second executeQuery to after you process your first while loop. You're probably overwriting

```
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select empname,empno from emp");
                    int row = 1;
        //first query iterate
        while(rs.next()) {

            String empname= rs.getString("empname");

            int empno = rs.getInt("empno ");
            Row dataRow = sheet.createRow(row);

            Cell dataNameCell = dataRow.createCell(0);
            dataNameCell.setCellValue(dateValue);

            Cell dataAddressCell = dataRow.createCell(1);
            dataAddressCell.setCellValue(empno );
            row = row + 1;
        }
        ResultSet rs1=stmt.executeQuery("select deptno,deptname from dept");
```

Comment: now i am getting only rs query output stored in the excel,but still i want both the queries data to be stored..

Comment: Statement stmt =  c.createStatement();

Comment: Create another statement stmt2

Comment: @ CocoNess it didnot made any changes..still the first rs loop is getting executed

Comment: I'm not sure if you want the 2nd rowset data to follow from the first in the same sheet. Where did you declare row1 variable? I suggest change row1 to row

Comment: i have done with the changes and tried with new create statement/without new create statement..getting the same result.only the first while is getting executed

Comment: Change the name of your row1 variable to row

Comment: can anyone help me out